# SSL not working on ubuntu server with multiple vhosts

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I run an Ubuntu (17.04) server that is hosting multiple sites. One of the sites I'm hosting now is an eCommerce site and needs an SSL certificate. I've gone through many different tutorials and I've followed every step but when I go to the site with HTTPS I'm just getting an error page.

The domain name in the screenshots below is fake.

First I bought the SSL certificate from Comodo. They requested the CSR from the server so I generated it using this command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr
```

I pasted the CSR and generated the CRT without issue. Now I have the CRT from Comodo and Updated my vhost for a secure connection:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin test@test.com
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_domain_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domain_com.key

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I then ran:

```
a2enmod ssl
```

And finally restarted apache. Now when I go to the site I'm only seeing this error page:

[image]

Looking at the apache error log the only hint to what might be wrong is the below message:

```
[Thu Aug 17 16:42:42.746221 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19871] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 17 16:42:42.836087 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 22306] AH01909: 2001:4802:7801:103:be76:4eff:fe20:7c04:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 16:42:42.874200 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 22316] AH01909: 2001:4802:7801:103:be76:4eff:fe20:7c04:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 16:42:42.878354 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22316] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 17 16:42:42.878374 2017] [core:notice] [pid 22316] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Any help would really be appreciated. This is the first time this server has had an SSL website so maybe I am missing a step with openSSL or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is buying a certificate from Namecheap.  I just recently had similar problems getting their crt to work.   It wasn't until I decided to with Let's Encrypt and used their certbot to generate the SSL certificate that I was able to resolve the problem.  I cannot prove this, but I suspect there is a problem with Namecheap's bundling tool which builds the signed certificate.

Let's Encrypt is a completely free open source project to solve your HTTPS needs.  I also have multiple virtual hosts and got up and running with Let's Encrypt in minutes.

https://letsencrypt.org/